# New terminology for left and right adjoints

Tags: category-theory, terminology, adjoint-functors

Let $C$, $D$ be categories and $F:C\to D$, $G: D\to C$ be functors.

Consider the following properties :

- $p_1$ : "$F$ is a left adjoint of $G$"
- $p_2$ : "$F$ has a right adjoint"
- $q_1$ : "$G$ is a right adjoint of $F$"
- $q_2$ : "$G$ has a left adjoint"

If you were to choose new names for these properties, what would be your choice ? Furthermore, what would be your notation for these properties?

PS: I'm asking this question because I don't like the usual terminology and I'm looking for a better one.

Comment: Your question is too opinion based. There is no way to tell if an answer is correct or incorrect. This is discouraged here.

Comment: I know but let’s hope someone comes with a nice answer before the question is closed. I don’t know where to ask this question otherwise. If anyone knows a better place than here, please let me know.

Comment: That said, and citing from the help center...
"It’s often possible to rewrite opinion-based questions to focus on a more fact-based line of questioning. If you see a way to do this, consider editing the question."

Comment: So for examxple you could ask "I dont like this terminology because such and such...(...). Do you know of a terminology that avoids this problem?" or something like that.

Comment: The chat may be more aproppiate, but in any case you should mention which aspects of the terminology are bothering you. Why it doesn't work for you, do you find it confusing, etc.

Comment: I can’t imagine someone liking this terminology.

Comment: This question should be closed as "opinion-based".

Comment: Well, the name 'adjoint functor' has been standardized for a while in category theory, so coming up a new name might lead to confusion. It really isn't a good idea to do this unless the new name has some absolute advantages. Even the name 'comma category' has been standardized, despite the name makes absolutely no connection to the definition, and the standard notation no longer uses comma

Comment: @Colas What is it that bothers you so much about this terminology?

Comment: It does not convey any intuition.

Comment: I don't like the left/right terminology because (i) it suggests that the distinction between left and right adjoints is only one of convention when in fact they are structurally different, and (ii) I don't know any sensible diagram I can draw where the left adjoint is on the left and the right adjoint is on the right, which makes the terms "left" and "right" unhelpful. I don't know a better terminology though. One could consider something like "inner" and "outer" adjoint, or even "lower" and "upper" - that would convey the asymmetry, but it still doesn't really give any intuition.

Comment: The problem is that left and right adjoints are really well established terms, so if you say anything else it will confuse people.

Comment: I know: it's for my own sake that I want to investigate this question.

Comment: @Nathaniel For me, a functor that has a right adjoint really feels different from one that has a left adjoint. I'm happy that you will feel the same: at least one person understands my question. I am looking for a different terminology and also notation. This situation makes me think of a couple with a man and a woman. I feel a forgetful functor more feminine for instance.

Comment: I'd advise to steer away from gender as an analogy - there are all sorts of reasons why that could be seen as problematic, socially speaking. I had a look into Categories for the Working Mathematician the other day, to see if I could find out where the terminology came from. It seems it's similar to "left" and "right" eigenvectors - the left and right refer to whether you're pre- or post-composing. I still don't think it's good terminology (especially since I write composition with the opposite convention to Mac Lane) but at least it gives some intuition for why they're called that.

Comment: Yes I know that gender analogies are problematic...

Answer (score 2):

You can say "left / right dual" instead of left / right adjoint, and also "left / right dualizable" for the conditions that such adjoints exist. This terminology comes from the theory of [dualizable objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object) in monoidal categories, which turn out to be essentially a specialization of left / right adjoints (once the latter are generalized to arbitrary 2-categories). "Dual" is unfortunately a very overloaded word in mathematics so it's not clear that this is really better.

One of the nice things about "adjoint" is that one of the only other uses of this word in mathematics is for a situation which is very analogous, namely adjoint linear transformations between inner product spaces. The idea is that there's an analogy between the hom-set definition of an adjunction

$$\text{Hom}(F(x), y) \cong \text{Hom}(x, G(y))$$

and the definition of an adjoint pair of linear transformations

$$\langle T(x), y \rangle = \langle x, T^{\dagger}(y) \rangle.$$

This analogy becomes very strong when considering [Frobenius reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_reciprocity), where the dimension of a hom space exactly recovers the inner product on characters of a finite or compact group.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu. Do you know other places (discord, forum, mailing list, etc.) where I could talk about this question of terminology?

Comment: @Colas: you could try the nForum: https://nforum.ncatlab.org/